# Text extraction using Matches activity

Tags: uipath, uipath-activity

I have a text file with data in it, I need to extract the data using `Matches` activity and pass it to an Excel.
My text file contains

```
-------------
Identifier :0
MT : 24
Sender : abc
Receiver : tyh
Send/Date : 02 February 2014
Send/Time : 00:00:09
MOR : 9876
CIP : 143
TRN
789
RR
09
NRT
ATTN: GURTEE
Text-----------
```

The above is an example of the text data so in that I need `MT, Sender, Receiver, Send\Date, Send\Time, MOR, CIP, number below TRN, number below RR and GURTEE from NRT`.